# WCF Castle Client Proxy leaving Channel Open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, castle

I am using Castle WCF Facility to initialise a client proxy using the following configuration:

```
  <component
 id="ComponentID"
 type="SomeType, SomeType"
 wcfEndpointConfiguration="WCFConfig"
 lifestyle="PerWebRequest" >
</component>
```

The problem I'm having is that in live I'm ending up with a large memory leak. Having analysed this with a memory profiler, I seem to have a large number of WCF Channels left in memory. Am I right to expect Castle WCF Facility to clean this up at the end of the web request?

Comment: Did you register the windsor httpmodule ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the lifestyle perwebrequest you need to ensure that HttpContext is not recreated throughout the request. If it is, then you need to pass HttpContext.Items around as Castle http modules use this to track the components.

e.g.

Changed this:

```
public CapturedViewResult Capture(ControllerContext controllerContext, Func<ActionResult> action)
    {
        CapturedViewResult capturedViewResult = new CapturedViewResult();

        HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
            HttpContext context = new HttpContext(currentContext.Request, response) { User = currentContext.User };
            context.Items["LocalizationContext"] = currentContext.Items["LocalizationContext"];

            HttpContext.Current = context;

            ViewResult result = action.Invoke() as ViewResult;

            if (result != null)
            {
                capturedViewResult.ViewName = result.ViewName;
                result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Supplied controller action method did not return a ViewResult", "action");
            }

            HttpContext.Current = currentContext;

            capturedViewResult.CapturedHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
        }

        return capturedViewResult;
    }
```

To this:

```
 public CapturedViewResult Capture(ControllerContext controllerContext, Func<ActionResult> action)
    {
        var capturedViewResult = new CapturedViewResult();

        var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var response = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
            var context = new HttpContext(currentContext.Request, response) { User = currentContext.User };

            foreach (var key in currentContext.Items.Keys)
            {
                context.Items.Add(key, currentContext.Items[key]);
            }

            HttpContext.Current = context;

            var result = action.Invoke() as ViewResult;

            if (result != null)
            {
                capturedViewResult.ViewName = result.ViewName;
                result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Supplied controller action method did not return a ViewResult", "action");
            }

            foreach (var key in context.Items.Keys)
            {
                currentContext.Items[key] = context.Items[key];
            }

            HttpContext.Current = currentContext;

            capturedViewResult.CapturedHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
        }

        return capturedViewResult;
    }
```